# Unable to serialize JSON serialize dictionary to file in Python

Tags: python, json, serialization, save

Apologize pretty new to python and I'm not 100% sure why this is failing since all example code I see is really similar.

```
import io
import json
import argparse
from object_detection.helpers import average_bbox

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-o","--output",required=True,help="Output file name.")
ap.add_argument("-c","--class",help="Object class name")
ap.add_argument("-a","--annotations",required=True,help="File path annotations are located in")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

(avgW,avgH) = average_bbox(args["annotations"])

if args["class"] is None:
    name = args["annotations"].split("/")[-1]
else:
    name = args["class"]

with io.open(args["output"],'w') as f:
    o = {}
    o["class"] = name
    o["avgWidth"] = avgW
    o["avgHeight"] = avgH
    f.write(json.dumps(o,f))
```

name, avgW and avgH are all valid values. avgW and avgH are numbers and name is a string. The output seems like a valid path to create a file. 
Error I get is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "compute_average_bbox.py", line 19, in <module>
    with io.open(argparse["output"],'w') as f:
TypeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The error message tells you what the problem is.

Comment: Did you confuse `args` and `argparse`?

Comment: Derp. Klaus is correct. I had to change it back to make another example format also, but those 2 changes make it work. Thanks.

Comment: I see you changed that `argparse` to `args` in your question. Does that code then still produce that error?

Comment: It produced a different one, but a combination of that fix and changing to arg instead of argparse fixed it.